# What is the difference between \cdots and \dotsm?

Tags: amsmath

`\cdots` and `\dotsm`, which I presume to stand for **c**enter **dots** and **dots** for **m**ultiplication, are both three dots in the middle of the line. I don't see the difference between them, and which is better to use in defining a variable like this?

Code: `S = 1!2! \dotsm 100!`

Output: [image: S = 1!2!...100!]

Similar question (not a duplicate): [What is the difference between ‎\ldots‎ and ‎\cdots‎?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117730/what-is-the-difference-between-ldots-and-cdots)

Comment: As is customary on this site, please show compilable code ([Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)). The two commands you mentioned don't exist in default LaTeX so it's impossible to reproduce your result and suggest anything. Thank you.

Comment: @Enderman note any version in a javascript emulation such as mathjax is off topic here, I answered the question assuming you were asking about latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using AoPS, so try doing it on the AoPS TeXer: https://artofproblemsolving.com/texer. Also, I think AoPS uses amsmath.

Comment: @Enderman ah so actually they are using tex (for the pdf option): `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) ` although they also show a mathjax option

Comment: @DavidCarlisle didn't know what AoPS used for LaTeX rendering so wasn't sure which tag to put there. What tags should I tag my post then?

Comment: `amsmath` as it is now is fine

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, After some research, I looked at https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Packages and figured out that AoPS indeed does use `amsmath`. So I was correct.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but your example might look better with a thinspace (`\,`) between 1! and 2!.

Comment: @mickep I'm fairly new (not that new) at LaTeX stuff so could you explain what that does? Does it just make it look better or something?

Comment: The `\,` inserts a thinmuskip which is `3mu` by default. You can have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11019/52406) to see the difference and judge for yourself if it is worth it.

Comment: @mickep Took a look, I don't think it is worth it so I will just leave it at that.

Comment: `\dotsm` stands for "*dots* for *m*ultiplication", not "*dots* *m*iddle".  It's part of the "semantic dots" group that includes `\dotsb` "*dots* for *b*inary operators", `\dotsc` "*dots* for *c*ommas", and `\dotsi` "*dots* for *i*ntegrals".  (I don't know when one should use `\dotsb` versus `\dotsm` when the binary operator is multiplication; I think perhaps the former is appropriate with an explicit operator symbol, and the latter when the operator is left implicit.)

Comment: @LSpice didn’t know that, fixed my post!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\cdots` is defined in the LaTeX format. `\dotsm`  is an alias in [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), defined as

```
\let\dotsm\cdots
```

So, `\cdots` and `\dotsm` are identical.

Comment: I see. However did you figure that out though? I would like to know!

Comment: @Enderman I knew the definition anyway (I have been maintaining LaTeX for 30 years:-) so I just copied the line from `amsmath.sty`. You could have used `\show\cdots` and `\show\dotsm` and compared the resulting messages.

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to know how you whipped up that answer so fast :-)